# How can I handle deleted branches with incremental git bundles?

Tags: git

I am trying to figure out the best way to mirror multiple git repos from one network to another.  I'll call the networks NetworkA and NetworkB.  NetworkA and NetworkB will never be connected to each other and no data can ever leave NetworkB (i.e. one way from A to B).

This scheme must be incremental because the quantity and size of repos on NetworkA would make full buldles take too long for regular sync tasks (bundle, copy to DVD, unbundle).

I have figured out how I can create the incremental bundles and have had success using mirrored clones on NetworkB to properly fetch data from the bundles.

The problem is, when an old (previously bundled) branch is deleted I have no way of including that information in a new bundle.  New bundles only contain the refs since the last bundle.  If I use git fetch --prune then all refs not in that specific bundle will be pruned which is not what I want either.

In the end, I have all of the objects and commits I need on the receiving side (NetworkB) but I have no good way to ensure that the refs themselves are properly synced on NetworkB.

One way I have thought to do this would be to create a packed-refs file on NetowrkA and then just copy that directly into the mirrored repo on NetworkB but that feels a bit dangerous.

Is there a "git" way to export and import packed-refs (just the refs, not the actual objects)?

Comment: Not really, but with `git for-each-ref` you can easily dump out each reference and its hash. Transport this to the other end and resolve in whatever specific way you would like (use the other plumbing command, `git update-ref`, to insert or delete refs into the mirror).